# WordPress not seeing vendor/autoload.php

Tags: php, wordpress, composer-php, environment, autoload

I'm learning how to create my own WordPress theme, so I have setup a local environment where I have a composer.json in the root along with the wp-content folder. As well as this I also have a composer.json in the theme folder for dependancies that are only for the theme. The problem I have is WordPress isn't reading the vendor/autoload which is in the root directory.

I am trying to load all my database details from an .env file which is loaded by the autoload.php. When I change the directory path for the autoload to the theme folder, everything works.

When I change it to use the autoload from the root, WordPress gives an error saying it cannot connect to the database. I have been trying several ways to get WordPress to read the autoload.php from the root directory vender folder, but it only works from the theme.

My code is:

```
require_once(dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php');
 $dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv( dirname( __DIR__ ) );
 $dotenv->load();
```

Any help or advice will be really appreciated. Thanks for taking the time to read my post.

Thanks

Comment: Here is a good article on using dotenv with wordpress. https://m.dotdev.co/secure-your-wordpress-config-with-dotenv-d939fcb06e24

Comment: @Kris Hi Chris thanks for the reply and the link to the article. I think the issue is the `require_once(dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php');` as the env works if I put the autoload in the theme folder. But what I'm trying to do is either put the vendor folder in the WordPress root or wp-content folder.

Answer (score -1):

It is recommended to put the 'vendor' folder inside your theme folder as it is the standard practice. This is why `dirname(__DIR__)` returns the theme or plugin path.

Although, if you still want to get the full directory path from the root...

For PHP < 5.3 use:

`$upOne = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/..');`

Or in PHP 5.3+ use:

```
$upOne = realpath(__DIR__ . '/..');
```